# Detect URL in NSString

Tags: ios, regex, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uitextview

I'm currently using a `UITextView` in a `UITableViewCell` in order to make links clickable, but this is giving very poor performance.

So I was wondering if it's possible to detect links in a `NSString` and if there is a link, use the `UITextView`, otherwise just use a `UILabel`.

Comment: Might be you can check for 'http' in NSString, if it contains then it is link.

Comment: @rishi, the problem is that there are many types of urls, UITextView seems to detect them all, so google.com, www.google.com, ...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Absolutely. Use NSDataDetector ([NSDataDetector Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html))

Comment: Woah, that worked perfectly, so easy, do this use the same "regex" as UITextView uses?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are familiar with regexes to detect URLs, so in order to get one or the other type of view in your cell, you can simply return two different `UITableViewCell`s from your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

It could look like this (please notice, typed in the browser not tested):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSString *dataString = // Get your string from the data model

    // Simple pattern found here: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL
    NSString *URLpattern = @"^http\\://[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(/\\S*)?$";

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSRegularExpression *URLregex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:URLpattern
                                                                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                                error: &error];

    NSUInteger numberOfMatches = [URLregex numberOfMatchesInString:string
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if ( numberOfMatches == 0 ) {
        static NSString *PlainCellIdentifier = @"PlainCellIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
        cell.textLabel.text = timeZoneWrapper.localeName;
    }
    else {
        static NSString *FancyCellIdentifier = @"FancyCellIdentifier";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

        // Configure cell view with text view here
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with regexes, especially not in objective-c, hence the question here

Comment: Thanks for the example, would there be a difference between using 2 custom cells, or just use one, but add the UITextView and UILabel in it and then remove one of them?

Comment: Yeah, I just added them in IB and removed them with code, in my case I would've to do a check anyway to set the row height

Answer (score 1):

Using this snip of code you would be able to find and get **http url in UILable** using NSDataDetector:

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
                NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:yourString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0,  [yourString. length])];
                NSLog(@"%@",matches) ;
                NSMutableAttributedString *MylabelAttributes = 
    [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];
                for (int index = 0 ; index < matches.count; index ++) {
                NSTextCheckingResult *textResult = [matches objectAtIndex : index]; 
                NSTextCheckingType textResultType = textResult.resultType;
                NSRange testRange = textResult.range;
                NSURL *testUrl = textResult.URL ;}

After applying this code, you will be able to attribute your `UILabel` text:

    [MylabelAttributes addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:testUrl  range: testRange];
    [MylabelAttributes addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName                       
    value:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:7.0]range:NSMakeRange(0,yourString.length)];
```